# Why aren't my floats lining up?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I've been staring at this problem for awhile now, and I was hoping someone on here could steer me in the right direction

For some reason I can't get my floats to line up the way i want them to! I managed to get the movie to the right, but when I want the two *floated* columns of reviewer's quotes to be up there right next to it.

[image: problem]

Here's my CSS Code that deals with the picture and the columns

```
.overview { /* The picture */
display:block;
float:right;
background-color: #A2B964;
}

.column1{
clear: left;
width: 31%;
margin-left: 2%;
margin-right: 1%;
}

.column2{
clear: left;
width: 31%;
margin-left: 1%;
margin-right: 2%;
}
```

Here is the HTML for the picture:

```
<div class = "overview">
            <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/12sp/homework/2/overview.png" alt="general overview" />
        </div>
```

And the HTML for the columns:

```
<div class = "column1">
        <p class = "quotebox">
            <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/12sp/homework/2/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" style="float:left;padding:5px;"/>
            <q>Ditching the cheeky, self-aware wink that helped to excuse the concept's inherent corniness, the movie attempts to look polished and 'cool,' but the been-there animation can't compete with the then-cutting-edge puppetry of the 1990 live-action movie.</q>
        </p>
        <p class = "reviewer">
            <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/12sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic" style="float:left;padding:5px;"/>
            Peter Debruge <br />
            <em>Variety</em>
        </p>

        <p class = "quotebox">
            <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/12sp/homework/2/fresh.gif" alt="Fresh" style="float:left;padding:5px;"/>
            <q>TMNT is a fun, action-filled adventure that will satisfy longtime fans and generate a legion of new ones.</q>
        </p>
        <p class = "reviewer">
            <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/12sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic" style="float:left;padding:5px;"/>
            Todd Gilchrist <br />
            <em>IGN Movies</em>
        </p>

        <p class = "quotebox">
            <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/12sp/homework/2/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" style="float:left;padding:5px;"/>
            <q>It stinks!</q>
            <br />
        </p>
        <p class = "reviewer">
            <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/12sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic" style="float:left;padding:5px;"/>
            Jay Sherman (unemployed)
        </p>

        <p class = "quotebox">
            <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/12sp/homework/2/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" style="float:left; padding:5px;"/>
            <q>The rubber suits are gone and they've been redone with fancy computer technology, but that hasn't stopped them from becoming dull.</q>
        </p>
        <p class = "reviewer">
            <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/12sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic" style="float:left;padding:5px;"/>
            Joshua Tyler <br />
            <em>CinemaBlend.com</em>
        </p>

        <p class = "quotebox">
            <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/12sp/homework/2/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" style="float:left;padding:5px;"/>
            <q>YOUR REVIEW HERE</q>
        </p>
        <p class = "reviewer">
            <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/12sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic" style="float:left;padding:5px;"/>
            NAME <br />
            <em>PUBLICATION</em>
        </p>
        </div>
        <div class = "column2">
        <p class = "quotebox">
            <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/12sp/homework/2/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" style="float:left;padding:5px;"/>
            <q>The turtles themselves may look prettier, but are no smarter; torn irreparably from their countercultural roots, our superheroes on the half shell have been firmly co-opted by the industry their creators once sought to spoof.</q>
        </p>
        <p class = "reviewer">
            <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/12sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic" style="float:left;padding:5px;"/>
            Jeannette Catsoulis <br />
            <em>New York Times</em>
        </p>

        <p class = "quotebox">
            <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/12sp/homework/2/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" style="float:left;padding:5px;"/>
            <q>Impersonally animated and arbitrarily plotted, the story appears to have been made up as the filmmakers went along.</q>
        </p>
        <p class = "reviewer">
            <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/12sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic" style="float:left;padding:5px;"/>
            Ed Gonzalez <br />
            <em>Slant Magazine</em>
        </p>

        <p class = "quotebox">
            <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/12sp/homework/2/fresh.gif" alt="Fresh" style="float:left;padding:5px;"/>
            <q>The striking use of image and motion allows each sequence to leave an impression. It's an accomplished restart to this franchise.</q>
        </p>
        <p class = "reviewer">
            <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/12sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic" style="float:left;padding:5px;"/>
            Mark Palermo <br />
            <em>Coast (Halifax, Nova Scotia)</em>
        </p>

        <p class = "quotebox">
            <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/12sp/homework/2/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" style="float:left;padding:5px;"/>
            <q>The script feels like it was computer generated. This mechanical presentation lacks the cheesy charm of the three live action films.</q>
        </p>
        <p class = "reviewer">
            <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/12sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic" style="float:left;padding:5px;"/>
            Steve Rhodes <br />
            <em>Internet Reviews</em>
        </p>

        <p class = "quotebox">
            <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/12sp/homework/2/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" style="float:left;padding:5px;"/>
            <q>YOUR REVIEW HERE</q>
        </p>
        <p class = "reviewer">
            <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/12sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic" style="float:left;padding:5px;"/>
            NAME <br />
            <em>PUBLICATION</em>
        </p>
        </div>
```

And for reference, as well as to clarify my question, the output it supposed to look like this: http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse190m/12sp/homework/2/output/out-wide.png

So can anyone see why my floated columns aren't sitting beside the TMNT logo?

Comment: Could you make a demo on jsfiddle.net ? That'll make things a lot easier to play with.

Comment: If it's too difficult to make a fiddle, may I suggest steering away from floats for this particular problem and using positioning to get the overview to be where you want it.

Comment: sorry I'm not really familiar with jsfiddle.net, and when i put it in there it comes out looking all bonkers

Comment: Yeah I figured that since you have a lot of images. Can you provide an actual link to page you're working on?

Comment: Cleaned up first post a bit, sorry i don't have anywhere to upload it -yet-

Comment: Alright well it's really hard to troubleshoot what's going on here without some example to work on :/ My best suggestion is to maybe start over on your assignment and just get a fresh take on everything. Otherwise I'm going to need more to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, heres what I did: http://jsfiddle.net/PR3un/

```
<div class = "overview">
    <img ... />
    <dl>...</dl>
</div>
```

The only differences I did were...

- Removed the clear:both,
- Moved  your dl into your ".overview" div
- Removed the overview class from your dl

Floats are tricky. My favorite analogy that I tell my coworkers is this:

> Using floats is like traveling through hyperspace. They exist, kinda, and can impact other DOM elements... but they are also travelling at a different dimensional plane (left-right). To bridge the float hyperspace travel, you can apply **clear:both on itself** or **overflow:hidden on its parent**.
>
> ... And if you **apply float on a floating element's parent**, it can provide a **self-clear**, but then the parent is traveling through hyperspace too.

Comment: So when you did <dl class = ""> is that just removing the overview class from it?

Comment: Yep, it didn't need to inherit the width:250, it gets that from its parent (which is "overview")

Comment: Also your subcontentarea was trying to set the "width" with a "weight". Updated at: http://jsfiddle.net/PR3un/1/

Comment: Fantastic! Well you seem like someone who is very experienced in this matter so thank you very much! And i love your analogy :)

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped. Heres a quick primer on floats (to illustrate what I was talking about earlier..) http://jsfiddle.net/PCjxN/